# Cosmos DB Emulator for Linux Docker “This is an evaluation version. There are [164] days left in the evaluation period”

Tags: linux, docker, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

I’m running Cosmos DB Emulator for Linux Docker image.

I’ve noticed the following message when the container starts running
“This is an evaluation version. There are [164] days left in the evaluation period”
Does this mean that after 164 days Cosmos DB Emulator will stop working? What can be done to extend the period or to replace the evaluation version with an image that does not expire?
I couldn’t find any information regarding this

And one more question: How can I migrate a complete Cosmos DB database from Azure to Cosmos DB Emulator Linux, running in docker on my local macOS?
I saw that there is Data Migration Tool for this that runs on Window, but is there a Data Migration Tool for Linux/macOS or is there another way to copy CosmosDB from Azure to Emulator?
Is there a service on Azure that can do that?
Can Data Migration Tool be built on macOS? If yes, is there a documentation on how to do that?

Also is there a way to send commands to the Cosmos DB Emulator for Linux running in docker (similar to what can be done on Windows https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/emulator-command-line-parameters). It would be nice if I could use *GetStatus* to check if Cosmos DB Emulator actually started.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question about the message *"This is an evaluation version. There are [N] days left in the evaluation period"* - I asked the Cosmos DB team at Microsoft and they said that the emulator will continue to work after the [N] days.  Apparently the counter should just reset back to 180 days and then count down again.

I don't think it is possible to send commands to a running Cosmos DB Emulator for Linux.  To see if it's started you could just make a call to it e.g. if you're using a client you could call https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.cosmosclient.readaccountasync and check it doesn't throw.

Comment: My evaluation period has ended and it now refuses to run. It throws this error now: "Error: The evaluation period has expired. ./palrun: ERROR: PAL initialization failed. Error: 104". Any ideas on how to get around this would be appreciated.

Comment: To fix my issue above, I deleted the container then removed and re-pulled the image.

Comment: remove the old image and volume and try to run docker with the latest version
`image: mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator:latest`